# Reactjs custom hooks generates jsx and controls events

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React hooks to generate reusable ui and events handling. Is it good to do?

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";

const CustomButton = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("hello");
  const lower = useRef(false);

  const onClick = () => {
    const newText = lower.current ? text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase();
    lower.current = !lower.current;
    setText(newText);
  };

  const add = () => {
    return <button onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>;
  };

  return { add };
};

export default CustomButton;
```

Comment: could you explain what you do?  what do you expect?

Comment: I have data to save and manipulate which includes communication between back-end services but not want to refresh UI for the moment. On the other hand, a component which uses the custom hook wants to draw the UI as well as using the data inside the hook. I can put all of data and UI into the component but it becomes the component too messy.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React;

const CustomButton = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("hello");
  const [isLowercase, setIsLowercase] = useState(false);
  // const lower = useRef(false);

  const onClick = () => {
    // const newText = lower.current ? text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase();
    // lower.current = !lower.current;
    const newText = isLowercase ? text.toUpperCase() : text.toLowerCase();
    setIsLowercase((prev)=>!prev);
    setText(newText);
  };

  const add = () => {
    return <button onClick={onClick}>{text}</button>;
  };
  // return { add }
  return add();
};


const App = () => (<CustomButton />)
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

I don't think you need `ref` if you want to use it only to change letters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code is just sample. I want to show there is some data stored inside the hook and it needs to be exposed to the outside. So, I missed the return { lower... }.

Comment: @SungwooPark 뭘 하시려는건지 모르겠습니당

Comment: `ref` 를 이용하여서 데이터를 가져온다는 말씀이신가요?

Comment: 네, ref를 써도 되는데, custom hook이 data 리턴이 가능한 점을 이용해서 위와 비슷한 형식으로 만들었거든요.